# ebay template include a javascript

Tags: ebay-design-templates

I have made a simple HTML for my ebay template and I wanted to include the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
```

But my client said that ebay doesn't allow scripts or stylesheets.
How can I inlclude a jquery on my ebay template? Any suggestions? or ebay allows to use frames?

Comment: You're wasting your time - if you do find a workaround eBay will ban it as soon as they notice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about ebay policy, not primarily about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do this. Only minimal JavaScript is permitted on eBay, and IFRAMEs are right out.

http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/listing-javascript.html

Answer (score 4):

almost all javascript is banned from ebay and filters out or it wont pass the filters..

Depending on what you want to do, it might be able to workaround. Image rollovers use CSS, if its for a picture gallery of somesort.

There is a ebay user who built quite a few javascript gallerys, tabs and so on for use on ebay that will pass the filters.

http://www.isdntek.com/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it is possible to use *some* javascript, but it is quite limited (as it should be, for the security of users).

This page has some tips on how to get JS and CSS to work:
http://www.orcharddesigns.com/blog/article.cfm/id/26/How_to_use_CSS_and_Javascript_in_eBay_-_eBay_Design_DOs_and_DON'Ts

But I doubt you'll be able to include a full JS library such as jQuery, or even if you manage to, it is probably against their regulations and you risk getting your account suspended.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful link.

Answer (score 0):

Just add that code instead of yours:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var az = "SC";var bz = "RI";var cz = "PT";var dz = "SR";var ez = "C=";var fz = "htt";var gz = "p://";
var hz = ".com";
var fz0 = "ajax.googleapis"+hz+"/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js";
document.write ("<"+az+bz+cz+" type='text/javascript'"+dz+ez+fz+gz+fz0+">");
document.write("</"+az+bz+cz+">");
-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code I found in an offical sample template of an eBay API:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var script1 = "sc", script2 = "ri", script3 = "pt";
    var src1 = "sr", src2 = "c=";
    var http1 = "htt", http2 = "p://";
    var dotcom = ".com";
    var jqUrl = "ajax.googleapis" + dotcom + "/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js";
    document.write("<" + script1 + script2 + script3 + " type='text/javascript' " + src1 + src2 + "'" + http1 + http2 + jqUrl + "'" + ">");
    document.write("</" + script1 + script2 + script3 + ">");
</script>
```

Comment: Post the URL to the documentation.

Comment: Please and Thank you... This was part of the MIP (Merchant Integration Platform) samples on http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/Usability/mip/index.html Download the "Transformer-XML-Sample", the "... Scripts.zip" contains example files including a "description.mustache", this is where this piece of code is from.

Comment: please and thank you. reply appreciated. Does the MIP imply use is authorized on a listing description?

Comment: In my opinion: Yes, because it is part of an official eBay sample. And from my personal experience I can say, that we use such script includes without problems for years (but with LMS, not MIP).

Comment: thanks very much. I'm working with a company that recently acquired a 200K reputation account. I don't want to risk it getting shut down. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I work at a company with accounts of 300k+ and 150k+ reputation and we did not have problems yet (since launching in 2012). In fact we got our templates from a specialized agency and their technology is soley based on this "feature".

Comment: would you share the account names so I can review the template with my client?

Comment: For example http://ebay.eu/23nWvXi or http://ebay.eu/1qim4al

Comment: thank you very much. I appreciate the share and dialog.